# Perl: "shift on reference is experimental"

Tags: perl

I am trying to get the first element of a list of sorted hash keys.

This works, as expected:

```
my $first = (sort keys %hash)[0];
```

These do not

```
my $first = shift sort keys %hash;

my $first = shift (sort keys %hash); # just in case
```

It throws the error

> shift on reference is experimental.
>   Not an ARRAY reference

What is going on?

This is a simple operation and I can't figure out where this supposed reference is. If there were a reference the first syntax wouldn't work.

I am using version 5.14 via `use` at the top of the script.

Comment: Try `my $first = shift @{[ sort keys %hash ]}`. See also [Documentation of backslash operator inducing list context for its operand is missing](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=131061)

Comment: `use v5.14` doesn't make you use Perl version 5.14. It says need your perl interpreter to be at least version 5.14, and you want to import all feature bundles in version 5.14.

Comment: Just to be sure (in case your example isn't an example but something you are actually doing): it's much faster and cleaner to use `min sort keys %hash` rather than `(sort keys %hash)[0]` (using `min` from [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) which is a core module).

Comment: @Dada `min keys %hash` surely? List doesn't need to be sorted to take its minimum.

Comment: `List::Util::min` operates on numerical values. `List::Util::minstr` is the function for finding the first element of a list in lexicographical order.

Comment: you could also do `List::Util::first {defined} sort keys %hash`

Comment: BTW, you must be using Perl 5.20 or 5.22, since those are the only two versions which produced the "shift on reference is experimental" message for your first non-working example. Perl versions before 5.14 had a slightly more helpful error message: "Type of arg 1 to shift must be array (not sort)".

Comment: @duskwuff oh right, I must have been tired when I wrote this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though the terms are often used interchangeably, [there is a distinction between a **list** and an **array** in Perl](https://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array). 
The `shift` operator expects an array and has a side-effect of modifying the array. The result of `sort keys %hash` is a list but not an array, and is not a valid argument for `shift`. There are some hacks to get `shift` to work with an arbitrary list

```
 $x = shift @{[sort keys %hash]}      # for example
```

but if you are calling `shift` just because you want the first element of the list, there are cleaner ways to do it.

```
my $first = (sort keys %hash)[0];
my ($first) = sort keys %hash;      # list context assignment
my $first = [sort keys %hash]->[0];
```

(I like the last construction, but I don't judge you if it rubs you the wrong way)

---

The "experimental" issue is that recent versions of Perl allow you to call `shift` on an array *reference*

```
@a = (1,2,3); print shift @a;    # 1
$a = [4,5,6]; print shift $a;    # 4
```

When you are calling `shift` on something that is not a named array, perl assumes you are using the `shift EXPR` form of the command, operating on an array reference. Since this is "experimental", you get a warning about that. Then perl discovers that what follows `shift` is not actually an ARRAY reference, and you get an error about that.

Comment: Who thought it was a good idea that this function should interpret a scalar reference to an array as an array when nothing else works that way?? Apparently someone agreed, because the documentation says this: "Starting with Perl 5.14, an experimental feature allowed shift to take a scalar expression. This experiment has been deemed unsuccessful, and was removed as of Perl 5.24."

Comment: @felwithe Well, a decent amount of functions assume their argument to be a ref when it's a scalar: `keys`, `values`, `pop`, `unshift`... And it makes sense: those functions can't take anything else than an array or a hash, so when called with a scalar, it would be logical that this scalar is a ref. (I guess it doesn't make *enough* sense though, since it was later removed)

Comment: So the answer is that it expects either a named array or a reference, but not an anonymous array? So if it was not version 5.14-5.24, it would error out with a different message?

Comment: @Dada: That is no longer true. It is a feature that was brought into the language and quickly removed. All of those functions now require an `@arr` or an `@$arr_ref` parameter.

Comment: @felwithe: No. The answer is that the operators expect an array. If you have an array reference then you must *dereference it*. Your examples show only attempts to apply `shift` to *lists*. Lists are *immutable constants*.

Comment: *"There are some hacks to get shift to work with an arbitrary list"* No. `shift @{[sort keys %hash]}` creates an array from the list, performs `shift` on it, and deletes the array. This is not a technique that you should represent.

Comment: @Borodin I know this is no longer the case (hence the "since it was later removed"). The point of my comment was merely to point out that `shift` doesn't have a unique behavior, and that it's not a irrational one, unlike what OP was saying/implying.