# Why does shift think it's receiving a parameter in scalar context?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to determine the maximum number of digits of any number in a list. I've found that I can easily chain functions. As such the following code works as expected:

```perl
use strict;
use diagnostics;

my @nums = qw/ 1 23 5432 45 /;
my @lengths = reverse sort map {1 + log($_)/log(10)} @nums;
my $max_length = shift @lengths;
printf "%d\n", $max_length;
```

Which produces the expected result of `4`.

However, when I try to do the shift on the same line as the rest of the list operations:

```perl
use strict;
use diagnostics;

my @nums = qw/ 1 23 5432 45 /;
my $max_length = shift reverse sort map {1 + log($_)/log(10)} @nums;
printf "%d\n", $max_length;
```

I get the error

```perl
Experimental shift on scalar is now forbidden at - line 5, near "@nums;"
```

Why does shift think that it's being passed a parameter with scalar context, but reverse and sort don't?

Thanks

Comment: The error message is misleading. What it's really saying is that the thing you are shifting is not a variable. You can get the same result with `my $scalar = shift (1,2,3);` When you had it in two lines, the shifted array is `@lengths`.

Comment: @RaymondChen It refers to older versions where, apart from an array, an expression also could've been passed (that evaluated to an arrayref).  I suppose that the message hinting at that is meant to be informative but I'd agree that it is probably just misleading at this point. Could just say 'EXPR unsupported' or such.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426146/perl-shift-on-reference-is-experimental/51426259

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note how the docs for [shift](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) say

> shift ARRAY
>   shift

Given that you aren't giving it an array (a variable) but an expression it dismisses it right away.

They later have a comment (my emphasis)

> Starting with Perl 5.14, an experimental feature allowed shift to take a **scalar** expression. This experiment has been deemed unsuccessful, and was removed as of Perl 5.24.

Clearly you are running 5.24 or newer version.

To understand the error message see docs for an older version, up until [5.22.4](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.22.4/functions/shift.html), with

> shift ARRAY
>   shift EXPR
>   shift

Note that there is no `LIST` there. They continued to explain what that EXPR stands for

> Starting with Perl 5.14, `shift` can take a scalar EXPR, which must hold a reference to an unblessed array. The argument will be dereferenced automatically. This aspect of `shift` is considered highly experimental.

So an older version, seeing an expression, would have computed it in the scalar context and passed that scalar to `shift`. (Then it would've complained about it not being an array reference.) Still having "*shift on scalar*" mentioned is meant to be informative but may be just confusing at this point.

Note that the length of a non-negative integer can be had by taking [length](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) of that string

```
my @lengths = reverse sort map { length } @nums;
```

what is far more efficient than taking logarithms.

Also, if you really need only the longest one

```
use List::Util qw(max);

my $max_length = max map { length } @nums;
```

what in this case can be done yet more efficiently as

```
my $max_length = length max @nums;
```

Comment: What's wrong with just using `length` to get the length?

Comment: Note that the `split` technique breaks down if the value is floating point or uses exponential notation. But if you assume that the values are all nonnegative integers that don't require exponential notation, it's probably faster to `max` first, and then calculate the length as a final step: `0 + split '', max @nums`.

Comment: @melpomene gulp, right ... got carried by something else I was doing ... fixing it .. thank you!

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, and I say that ("_integer's length_") ... I guess that still leaves room for exponential notation but should be enough of a hint.

Comment: @RaymondChen Sure, it's faster (for any reasonable data), thank you, added

Comment: Re "*To understand the error message see docs for an older version*", [A walk through history](https://pastebin.com/xqcxbGys)

Comment: @Jasper  This answer got edited a lot since you accepted it (thank you), and got improved in the process.  It's worth a look, I think, in case you haven't noticed.

Comment: @zdim Yeah I've been keeping up with the changes. Thanks, it's elucidated quite a few things!

Answer (score 1):

The following code achieves the OP's stated aim: "I'm trying to determine the maximum number of digits of any number in a list." He gets that maximum by taking the first element of an ephemeral array---an array that exists only for the duration of the sort statement.

The solution below does not answer the specific question about shift. But since the OP's array is anonymous (or defined implicitly---is it proper to call it anonymous?), and since it only exists for the duration of a single statement, the fact that `shift` removes the first element of an array means nothing here. What the OP wants is the value of the 1st element of the array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
my @nums = qw/ 1 23 5432 45 /;
printf "%d\n", [reverse sort map {1 + log($_)/log(10)} @nums]->[0];
```

This also solves a more general problem: How to get the `k`th element of an array, when the array is anonymous or has only been defined implicitly.

A review, requesting improvement of this answer, suggested
"explain how it's better / different than existing answers, if there are any."

Currently, the search term "how to find the kth element of an array defined implicitly" on stackoverflow brings up absolutely nothing. Same for "how to find the kth element of an anonymous array". So this provides an answer to that query.

For instance, if you want to know the last of the sorted keys of an array, you can do it in one statement thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
my %hash=(
   dog=>55,
   cat=>-99,
   'fleas bacteria'=>1e3,
   Romulus=>undef,
);
my $lastkey=[sort keys %hash]->[-1];
```

Comment: This answer was flagged for review as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not good answers** and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted  because they are **not useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers (if there are any). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29801658)