# How to shift block (key and value) from hash in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have the following partly code:

```
while(my $path = shift(@paths)) {
    # Do stuff
}
```

Inside the loop there is a case where I add another key to the `@paths` so in the next iteration it will handle that path.

I had to change the structure of `@paths` from array to hash. How can I replace the while-loop? From this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426146/perl-shift-on-reference-is-experimental), I tried:

```
while(my $path = shift(@{[keys(%paths)]}))
```

But the problem is that it will do an infinite loop since the shift works on the anonymous array and not on `%paths`. Also I need to keep in mind the case where I update the `%paths` inside the loop:

```
my $p = "/some/path";
$paths{$p} = "open";
```

So that in one of the next iterations of the loop it will handle this path as well. I also can't use `foreach` since I update `%paths`. What would be the best solution here?

Comment: This is almost certainly a bad idea, whatever it is you are trying to do. You should describe what problem you are trying to solve by this strange solution.

Comment: OP is processing a list, and the processing can add new elements to the list.

Comment: "_add another key ... so in the next iteration it will handle that path_"  --- once you switch to a hash, must the new key still be processed in the very next iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrieve the key, then `delete` the hash entry

```
while (my ($key) = keys %paths) {       # NB: list context assignment
    my $value = delete $paths{$key};
    ...
}
```

Comment: If `"0"` or `""` can be a hash key, you also need to test `defined($key)`

Comment: Or just `while (keys %paths) { my ($key) = keys %paths; delete $paths{$key}; ... }`

Comment: Or just put the keys into an array and shift from that....

Comment: Note that mob and choroba's approach will be extremely slow for longer lists. The efficient way: `while (keys %paths) { my ($key, $val) = each %paths; keys %paths; delete $paths{$key}; ... }`. Ugly as hell. See my answer for a better approach.

Comment: @TLP, Then you'd have to keep the hash and the list in sync. There's a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use a bare block with manual loop control:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
    foo => 1,
    bar => 2,
    baz => 3,
);

HASH: {
    my ($key) = keys %hash;
    my $value = delete $hash{$key};
    
    print "$key => $value\n";
    
    # Sometimes new values will be added to the hash.
    #
    if ( $key eq 'foo' ) {
        $hash{quux} = 42;
    }
    
    redo HASH if %hash;
};
```

I feel bare block loops are underused.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing you were doing before, but with a different queue:

```
my @queue = keys %path;

while( my $key = shift @queue ) {
    $path{$new_key} = ...;
    push @queue, $new_key;
    }
```

I'm generally nervous about changing the data structure that I'm iterating over. Perl can have some weird effect there.

Answer (score 1):

It was a mistake to switch to a hash. Use an array of path-value pairs.

```perl
my @todo = ( [ "/some/path", "open" ] );
while (@todo) {
   my ($path, $value) = @{ shift(@todo) };

   ...

   push @todo, [ ..., ... ];

   ...
}
```